# add values ​to an array recursively pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

i have two table INFOAGENT (agent information), HIERARCHIAGENT (the hierarchical attachment of each agent) I wish to make a procedure (pl/sql) which adds recursively  in a array the paramidal hierarchy of a company until  the agent code passed on in parametre, and return the array beginning by the CEO

Here is the data.

```
INFOAGENT 
ID           NAME
P001         AAAA
P002         BBBB
P003         CCCC
P004         DDDD
P005         EEEE
P006         FFFF

HIERARCHIAGENT 
INCHARGE     IDAGENT
P001         P002
P001         P003         
P002         P005
P003         P006
P003         P004
```

I tried this

```
type hierarchie is table of INFOAGENT.ID%TYPE index by binary_integer;
create or replace PROCEDURE AGENTHIERARCHIE ( codeagent INFOAGENT.ID%TYPE,
                                      arrayresponse out hierarchie%TYPE)
AS

DECLARE

arrayresponse hierarchie;

cursor cur is SELECT ID FROM INFOAGENT where ID= codeagent

begin 

FOR rec_agent in cur LOOP
// i don't know how to do it here 

end loop;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(replace(sqlerrm,'ORA-','ORA_'));

END AGENTHIERARCHIE ;
```

Comment: Does this have to be done recursively? Why not just use `CONNECT BY` in your for loop cursor?

Comment: yes, but can you tell how to do it whithout recusivity

Comment: Please see recursive solution below. If you would add the "recursion" tag to your question, it will be more helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might meet your requirements. At least, it can help you get started.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE hierarcy_defs AS
  TYPE hierarcy IS TABLE OF INFOAGENT.ID%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
END hierarcy_defs;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE agenthierarchy (
  codeagent     IN     infoagent.id%TYPE,
  p_index       IN     BINARY_INTEGER,
  arrayresponse IN OUT hierarcy_defs.hierarcy)
AS
  i BINARY_INTEGER;
  l_codeagent infoagent.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  i := p_index;

  arrayresponse(i) := codeagent;

  BEGIN
    SELECT incharge
    INTO   l_codeagent
    FROM   hierarchiagent
    WHERE  idagent = codeagent;

    i := i + 1;

    agenthierarchy(l_codeagent, i, arrayresponse);
  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      FOR j IN arrayresponse.FIRST .. arrayresponse.LAST
      LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(arrayresponse(j));
      END LOOP;
  END;  
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(REPLACE(SQLERRM,'ORA-','ORA_'));
END agenthierarchy;
```

Anonymous block for testing:

```
DECLARE
  l_arrayresponse hierarcy_defs.hierarcy;
BEGIN
  agenthierarchy('P006', 1, l_arrayresponse);
END;
```